# PHP shell_exec() function printing different outputs of running wc command on a hindi text file in console and browser

Tags: php

I have a text file containing Indic/hindi text
I have made a simple php code to take output of wc command in a string/stream using shell_exec().
My code of wc.php is as follows ::

```
<?php
$filename = '/tmp/1371272031.txt';
//above file contains hindi text
$cmd = 'wc ' . $filename;
$wcoutput = shell_exec($cmd);
echo $wcoutput;
?>
```

The file '/tmp/1371272031.txt ' contains text in hindi.

When i run this code from terminal 
 with command

```
php wc.php
```

then i get the output like running wc command in terminal  "wc /tmp/1371272031.txt"

out put is this ::

```
 5  9 74 /tmp/1371272031.txt
```

But when i run this code from browser like http://dashboard2.iiit.ac.in/abc/wc.php
It gives output like

```
5  0 74 /tmp/1371272031.txt
```

It gives the output different in browser.
Please explain and try to help me out of this issue.

Comment: probably different language/encoding settings between the console user vs the user running the web server.

Comment: Yes, i have seen that that text file data is in UTF-8 format, not in ACSII. But i dont know why that same php code when i run it from console, it is giving the correct output but on web browser it is giving different output.

Comment: The character encoding of my terminal and my browser are both UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the locale in the PHP-script, before executing `shell_exec()`. Something like this.

`putenv("LANG=C.UTF-8");`

Worked for me on Linux.